# Formula for wedge product

Tags: differential-topology, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

Suppose that $\phi_1,...,\phi_k\in V^*$ and $v_1,...,v_k\in V$, where $k=\dim V$. I am trying to show that $\phi_1\wedge\cdots\wedge \phi_k(v_1,...,v_k)=\frac{1}{k!}\det[\phi_i(v_j)]$, where $[\phi_i(v_j)]$ is a $k\times k$ matrix.

If the $\phi_i$ are linearly dependent, then the wedge product equals zero, and so we have the result. I am told to check the result for the dual basis in $V$. So suppose that $v_1,...,v_k$ form a basis for $V$ and that $\phi_1,...,\phi_k$ form the dual basis. The formula I have for the wedge product is $T\wedge S=\text{Alt}(T\otimes S)$, where $T$ is a $p$-tensor, $S$ a $q$-tensor, and $T\otimes S(v_1,...,v_p,v_{p+1},...,v_{p+q})=T(v_1,...,v_p)S(v_{p+1},...,s_{p+q})$, and where $\text{Alt}(T)=\frac{1}{p!}\sum_{\pi\in S_p}\text{sign}(\pi)T^\pi$, where $T^\pi=\text{sign}(\pi)T$.

Using these definitions, I have the following: Since each $\phi_i$ is a $1$-tensor, we do not have to worry about the sign, since every permutation will be the identity. So I have that $\phi_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\phi_k=\text{Alt}(\phi_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\phi_k)=\frac{1}{k!}(\phi_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\phi_k)$, and so $\frac{1}{k!}(\phi_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\phi_k)(v_1,...,v_k)=\frac{1}{k!}\phi_1(v_1)\cdots\phi_k(v_k)=\frac{1}{k!}$.

Is this computation correct? I am a little confused about what he matrix $[\phi_i(v_j)]$ is supposed to look like. The next part of the question asks me to "verify that the matrix does specify an alternating $k$-tensor on $V$, but I am not sure what this means. I know $\det$ is a tensor, but why is the matrix itself a tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computation is wrong, although you arrive to the correct result for the dual basis. Each $\phi_i$ is a 1-tensor, right, but you're computing $Alt$ of a tensor product of $k$ 1-tensors, which is a $k$-tensor, so you do have to take into account the sign of each permutation of $S_k$.

The matrix $[\phi_i(v_j)]$ is just the matrix

$
\begin{pmatrix}
\phi_1(v_1) & \cdots & \phi_1(v_k)\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
\phi_k(v_1) & \cdots & \phi_k(v_k)
\end{pmatrix}
$

If you take into account the sign of the permutations and recall the definition of the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Definition) in terms of permutations, you will get to the desired formula. In particular, for the dual basis, you get the identity matrix, whose determinant is $1$.

For your second question, I guess that the tensor specified by the matrix is the $\det$ tensor, so you have to verify that it is alternating. Another possibility is that, since every matrix defines a linear map, it defines a 1-tensor, but I consider this option unlikely since every linear map is trivially alternating.

Comment: Wouldn't that matrix just be the identity matrix? If so, shouldn't we still get the wedge product to be equal to $1/k!$?

Comment: And do you mean the sign of every permutation in $S_k$?

Comment: In general it's not the identity matrix, because $\phi_i$ is not specified to be dual to $v_i$.

Comment: I mean, in the formula for $Alt(\phi_1\otimes \cdots\otimes\phi_k)$. You've got a sum over $\pi\in S_k$, in which each term is multiplied by $sign(\pi)$, so yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: The problem asked to check for the dual basis, so wouldn't that just give the identity?

Comment: Oh, cool, I didn't read well, for the dual basis it would give you the identity matrix.